# Can you determine the memory footprint of a collection?

Tags: java

I have an in-memory collection that I want to flush to disk once it has reached either a certain size (count wise) or memory footprint.

How can I determine how much memory a collection is using?

It is going to be some sort of Dictionary/Map.

Comment: You can use `JVisualVM` in JDK bin folder which has a profiler after activating JMX in your app. To activate JMX from your app, you need to set program arguments (or use `System.setProperty()` without `-D`) with following values: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<define TCP port number here>`. Then run JVisualVM; you will see your app in the list, click on it to monitor CPU, memory, threads, class count. Check profiler section to see more details on CPU and memory

Answer (score 6):

You can't, easily. For example, consider an `ArrayList<String>` with a backing array of size 256 and an "in use" size of 200, where each string is 20 characters long, backed by a 30 character backing array.

It *sounds* like you could easily work out how much memory that's taking - but if every element in the array is actually a reference to the *same* string, then obviously it takes a lot less memory. That's just for `String`, which is a class which is *relatively* straightforward to analyze. For classes with various mixtures of definitely-distinct and possibly-shared references, it becomes even more complicated.

You could serialize it - but that only shows you how much space it takes up when serialized, not in memory.

I suggest you experiment and find some appropriate "average" size, derive a maximum *count* that makes sense, and just go on that basis.

Comment: I was curious as some caching services allow you to set a maximum size of memory they will use, how else could they prevent someone from adding more items if they have reached their e.g. 1G max?

Comment: @codecompleting: I suspect those systems are serializing the data in some form when it's added to the cache. (It doesn't need to be Java's built-in binary serialization, but *some* form of serialization.) Or custom JVM implementations of course...

Comment: well since these caching services get their data sent to them (they are a service reached on a port), the data is streamed right?  so they know the byte count from there I guess?  So they can keep a running total of the size of each value right?

Comment: @codecompleting: Well now you're giving *some* more information about the caching services... before now you'd just talked about "some caching services" which could have meant just about anything. In that case, they may be just storing the raw data as a byte array, which is an entirely different matter.